# Wierd errors on my visual studio when working with Memory.dll or just doing anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a question about viusal studio 2019 community edition.
So i use it for unity mostly,i dont really build any programs on it.
So i started to use it to make a simple programm and it just drops an error and idk what to do:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error:The package ID 'Redac Rijeci' contains invalid characters. Examples of valid package IDs include 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'.Redac Rijeci C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets 221
Ive reinstalled it and repaired it but it still doesnt work,it still says the same so i jumped straight to the thing i started using it for.
Memory.dll
So i saw u can hack games with it and i wondered if someone could hack my game so i went and build a little ingame anticheat that swaps values between variables.
next i found some yt tutorial how to build it and i learned a few thing along the way,and i compiled it and boom,an error:

System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Memory, Version=1.2.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

I tried a few thing but it doesnt help.
My code is perfect i even compared it to the source code on github its the same just the variables have different names.

So should i unistall vs2019 and switch to 2020 or lower version or?
Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure that both the host (exe) and the Memory.dll are built for the same architecture (platform), when the .dll is not built for AnyCPU.

1. host is x86 & dll is AnyCPU -> works
2. host is x64 & dll is AnyCPU -> works
3. host is x86 & dll is x64 -> does not work
4. host is x64 & dll is x86 -> does not work

Give it a try.

Regards

Comment: Oh sorry it was the x64 - x86 problem and i added it onto my configuration manager and now it works,it doesnt show any compiler errors and its good,Thank You.I tought it was already x64 bc my system is x64 but ok now i know what to do if this happens ever again